# joomla module include_once issue

Tags: php, joomla, youtube, include

I am in the middle of creating a youtube playlist module for joomla.

If I assign the module to a page, it stops loading at the following point:

```
<div class="youtubeplayer">
    <div class="yt_holder">
            <!--Up and Down arrow -->
            <div class="you_up"><img src="modules/mod_youtube_playlist/css/up_arrow.png" alt="+ Slide" title="HIDE" /></div>
            <div class="you_down"><img src="modules/mod_youtube_playlist/css/down_arrow.png" alt="- Slide" title="SHOW" /></div>
            <!-- END  -->
        <div id="ytvideo3"></div>
            <div class="youplayer">
            <ul class="videoyou">
```

It looks to be stopping where I use the 'include once' in the following code (the below code is my modules "tmpl/default.php" file) - any ideas?

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

JHtml::_('behavior.framework');

JHtml::script('modules/mod_youtube_playlist/js/jquery.youtubeplaylist.js');
JHtml::script('modules/mod_youtube_playlist/js/jquery.jquery.youtubeplaylist-min.js.js');
JHtml::script('modules/mod_youtube_playlist/js/youtubeplaylist.js');
JHtml::stylesheet('modules/mod_youtube_playlist/css/youtubeplaylist.css');
JHtml::stylesheet('modules/mod_youtube_playlist/css/indext.css');
?>

<div class="youtubeplayer">
    <div class="yt_holder">
            <!--Up and Down arrow -->
            <div class="you_up"><img src="modules/mod_youtube_playlist/css/up_arrow.png" alt="+ Slide" title="HIDE" /></div>
            <div class="you_down"><img src="modules/mod_youtube_playlist/css/down_arrow.png" alt="- Slide" title="SHOW" /></div>
            <!-- END  -->
        <div id="ytvideo3"></div>
            <div class="youplayer">
            <ul class="videoyou">
            <?php
            // Use like this.
            include_once('/modules/mod_youtube_playlist/class/class.youtubelist.php');
            //in this example a playlist
            $video = new youtubelist('playlist');
            //This is the link to the playlist.
            //http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC4FBCA46405A8BF8
            //REMOVE the PL from the string if there is an PL after list=
            $video->set_playlist('<?php echo $playlist; ?>');
            $video->set_max(50);
            $video->set_order('title');
            $video->set_cachexml(false);
            $video->set_cachelife(86400);
            $video->set_xmlpath('./cache/');
            $video->set_start(1);

            if ( $video->get_videos() !=null ) {
                foreach ($video->get_videos() as $yKey => $yValue) {
                    echo '<li><p>' . $yValue['title'] . '</p><span class="time">' . $yValue['time'] . '</span><a class="videoThumb3" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $yValue['videoid'] . '">' . $yValue['description'] . '</a></li>';
                }
            }else{
                echo '<li>Sorry, no video\'s found</li>';
            }
            ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you getting any php error in this ...?????

Answer (score 1):

Using that path `/modules/mod_youtube_playlist/....` will be looking in the server's root and not your site root.

I suspect you are getting a fatal error on that include because it is not found.

You can use the `JPATH_BASE` constant which is the path to your site root:

```
include_once(JPATH_BASE . '/modules/mod_youtube_playlist/class/class.youtubelist.php');
```

For future debugging you should turn errors on (or look in the error log) and if posting here at SO, always include the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

rather than using this:

```
JHtml::script('modules/mod_youtube_playlist/js/jquery.youtubeplaylist.js');
JHtml::stylesheet('modules/mod_youtube_playlist/css/indext.css');
```

try this:

```
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addStyleSheet(JURI::root() . "modules/mod_youtube_playlist/css/indext.css");
$document->addScript(JURI::root() . "modules/mod_youtube_playlist/js/jquery.youtubeplaylist.js");
```

would also recommend using ROOT instead of BASE when including.